# Can I call a web page and include it into other web page using restful

Tags: javascript, html, rest

I have an HTML page (pageChild) containing Javascript and some functionality, on the other hand I have the landing page that should call other sub page (e.g.: pageChil) without reloading the whole page, can I use restful web service to call such subpage and then include it in a div? what about the javascript is still function properly in pageChild?
I don't want to use iframe.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use an iFrame? Does the other page have the div elements you need or is it an entire page with its own `<html><head><body>` tags?

Comment: <?php require 'child.html';?> is this what you are going for?

Comment: The question isn't really clear as to what OP actually wants to achieve, but I believe that an AJAX request could be what he is looking for.